# Drop in Javascript component - How to handle ‘configuration'

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to create a Javascript component that I can simply ‘include’ on a page and it *basically* outputs a form.
I will probably use Handlebars templates within my component.

However, I’m struggling with how best to structure the configuration of my component
I thought of some how passing it in like:

```
<script src = “my-component.js”>
    var config = {
        key1: ‘whatever’,
        key2: ‘whatever'
    }
</script>
```

...But how could I then get hold of my `config` object, within `my-component.js`?
Is there a more preferred approac

Comment: Well that is an invalid script, you cannot have both a src attribute and text within the script tags, you have to have one or the other..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments already, an external file and a script body don't mix. Working in separate files with `window` objects and/or Constructor functions is.
The terminology for these combinations of objects varies in different ways.

One of those important starter functions is an IIFE (Immediatly Invoked Function Expression)

```
// wrap an anonymous function
(function(window){
    /*  window available as private variable */
}(window)); // calls the function with global window as parameter
```

With this little setup, you can:

- bind/use objects from parameters in a private way
- use libraries in a "safe" way
- instantiate modules automatically and in sequence
- create accessible modules/components
- ...

To combine this into a module pattern, as your initial request, you need a file to load modules, and you need module files.

**The loader file:**

```
(function () {

    // 1. PRIVATE INITIALIZER
    function init() {
        Project.classes();
        Project.components();
    }

    // 2. CONFIGURATION OVERRIDE
    var cfg = {
        modTwo: {
            container: '[data-module="two"]'
        }
    };

    // 3. GLOBAL NAMESPACE
    window.Project = {
        // allows optional configuration on the object
        classes: function () {
            return {
                moduleOne: new Project.ModuleOne(),
                moduleTwo: new Project.ModuleOne(cfg.modTwo)
            };
        },

        // has private configuration
        components: function () {
            Project.Cookiebox.init();
        }
    };

    // 4. ON WINDOW LOAD
    window.addEventListener('load', init);

}());
```

**A typical module file:**

```
/**
 * @param        {Function} $ jQuery v1.11.1
 * @param        {Object} project
 */
window.Project = (function ($, project) {
    // 1. CONFIGURATION
    var cfg = {
        container: '[data-module="one"]'
    };

    // 2. CONSTRUCTOR
    project.ModuleOne = function (options) {
        this.settings = $.extend(true, {}, cfg, options);
        this.init();
    };

    // 3. PROTOTYPE OBJECT
    project.ModuleOne.prototype = {

        version: 0.1,

        init: function () {
            this.cacheItems();

            if (this.container.length) {
                this.bindEvents();   
            }
        },

        cacheItems: function () {
            this.container = $(this.settings.container);
        },

        bindEvents: function(){
            this.container.on('click', function(ev){
                /*do something*/
            });
        }
    };

    // 4. GLOBALIZE NAMESPACE
    return project;

}(window.jQuery, window.Project || {}));
```

**A typical component file** (slightly different):

```
/**
 * @param        {Function} $ jQuery v1.11.1
 * @param        {Object} project
 */
window.Project = (function ($, project) {

    // 1. CONFIGURATION
    var cfg = {
        container: '[data-component="cookiebox"]'
    };

    // 2. COMPONENT OBJECT
    project.Cookiebox = {

        version: 0.1,

        init: function () {
            this.cacheItems();

            if (this.container.length){
                this.bindEvents();
            }
        },

        cacheItems: function () {
            this.container = $(cfg.container);
        },

        bindEvents: function () {
            this.container.on('click', function () {
                /* set cookie and toggle the container */
            });
        }
    };

    // 3. GLOBALIZE NAMESPACE
    return project;

}(window.jQuery, window.Project || {}));
```

Then in your HTML output it should look similar to this:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://path-to-jquery.js">/*preferably minified and bundled*/</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-module="one"></div>
    <div data-module="two"></div>
    <div data-component="cookiebox"></div>
    <script src="http://path-to-loader.js">/*preferably minified and bundled*/</script>
    <script src="http://path-to-moduleone.js">/*preferably minified and bundled*/</script>
    <script src="http://path-to-cookiebox.js">/*preferably minified and bundled*/</script>
</body>
```

I can keep adding information here and there but it looks like it's getting too much already. Let me know if this interests you and further explanation is required.